# new line in JLabel and JTextField in Flow Layout

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, multiline

I am using `FlowLayout` and trying to make `JLabels` and `JTextField` in order but I am stuck and do not know how to do it.

```
public class SoftwareProducts extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    JTextField ramtf;
    JTextField processortf;
    JTextField productIDtf;
    JTextField productNametf;
    JTextField productYeartf;
    JTextField productPublishHousetf;

    JButton CompleteOrder;

    JLabel Ramlb = new JLabel("RAM:");
    JLabel processorlb = new JLabel("Processor:");
    JLabel productIDlb = new JLabel("Product ID");
    JLabel productNamelb = new JLabel("Product Name:");
    JLabel productYearlb = new JLabel("Product Year:");
    JLabel PublishHouselb = new JLabel("Publish House:");

    JPanel softwarePanel;
    CardLayout c2 = new CardLayout();

    CompleteOrder completeOrder;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SoftwareProducts();
    }

    public SoftwareProducts() {
        setSize(500, 300);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        add(Ramlb);
        Ramlb.setFont(new Font("Arial", 5, 28));
        ramtf = new JTextField(15);
        add(ramtf);
        ramtf.addActionListener(this);
        add(processorlb);
        processortf = new JTextField(15);
        processortf.addActionListener(this);
        add(processortf);
        add(productIDlb);
        productIDtf = new JTextField(10);
        productIDtf.addActionListener(this);
        add(productIDtf);
        add(productNamelb);
        add(productNamelb);
        productNametf = new JTextField(10);
        productNametf.addActionListener(this);
        add(productNametf);
        add(productYearlb);
        productYeartf = new JTextField(10);
        productYeartf.addActionListener(this);
        add(productYeartf);
        add(PublishHouselb);
        productPublishHousetf = new JTextField(10);
        productPublishHousetf.addActionListener(this);
        add(productPublishHousetf);
        CompleteOrder = new JButton("CompleteOrder");
        CompleteOrder.setSize(25, 40);
        CompleteOrder.addActionListener(this);
        add(CompleteOrder);
        softwarePanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        softwarePanel.add(Ramlb);
        softwarePanel.setLayout(c2);
        completeOrder = new CompleteOrder();
        softwarePanel.add(new JPanel(), "empty");
        softwarePanel.add(completeOrder, "completeOrder");
        this.add(softwarePanel);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == CompleteOrder) {
            c2.show(softwarePanel, "completeOrder");
            float ram = Float.parseFloat(ramtf.getText());
            float processor = Float.parseFloat(processortf.getText());
            int productID = Integer.parseInt(productIDtf.getText());
            String productName = productNametf.getText();
            int productYear = Integer.parseInt(productYeartf.getText());
            String productPublishHouse = productPublishHousetf.getText();

            main.softwareList.add(new Software(productID, productName, productYear, productPublishHouse));
            ramtf.setText("");
            System.out.println("Saved");
        }
    }
}
```

What code would result in it new lines breaks in each line? Shat should to be done to make the line breaks down in `JLabel` and `LTextField`?

Comment: It sounds like `FlowLayout` is simply the wrong layout manager for your purposes.  I'm having trouble understanding what layout you are actually trying to achieve, but `FlowLayout` just lays out components in text order (left-to-right, top-to bottom in most locales) without any extra space between.

Comment: there are a number of ways to do this, but personally I recommend GridBagLayout

Comment: Thanks for your information ::

Answer (score 2):

These are two completely different problems and neither of them has anything to do with the LayoutManager.

For the `JTextField`:
Taken from the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?javax/swing/JTextField.html):

> JTextField is a lightweight component that allows the editing of a single line of text

There's no way at all to add a newline to a `JTextField` (atleast no legit way). Use a `JTextArea` instead; newlines are just like in the console `\n`.

`JLable` like most other `JComponent`s aswell can process and display HTML-code. So a newline in a `JLabel` would look like this:

```
JLabel twoLined = new JLabel("This is one line</br>And this is another one");
```

Comment: @JoopEggen yes, that's a more accurate way, should produce the same result though